# Not able to create table in SQL job

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

If I need to delete data from any of the  table from my database,first I will create backup table and move data  in my backup database by date and time and I will delete the data. all the above process i'm doing inside an procedure, my delete script I'm pass as an input parameter. If i run the procedure manually it is Woking and my data also creating in backup table.
But, if I keep this exce procedure inside a SQL server agent job Data is deleting but not able to create table in my backup database.

Can anybody pls give me a solution to why my table is not creating inside SQL job.

Comment: Maybe the SQL agent doesn't have permission to create tables?   What error do you get when it runs from the job?

Comment: Like @TabAlleman said, make sure that the service account that runs the SQL Server Agent has create table rights or is a member of at least the ddladmin role.

Comment: Hi @TabAlleman I have full rights on SQL server Agent and my job running successfully I'm not getting any error..

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you need to grant the service account that runs SQL Server Agent, ddladmin permissions

```
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember 'db_ddladmin', [serviceaccount]
```

or permissions to create tables:

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE to [serviceaccount];
```